# Removing ccLabelBMFONT And Placing New one at the same palce from another Class

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Once again I need your Help, am thanking you as every time you helped me.

I am developing Game in iPhone using 'COCOS2D' framework and 'OBJECTIVE-C'. In my game there is Ten(10) Levels. The LEVEL Label is created and defined in a class ( i:e HudLayer.h, HudLayer.m ) and I am removing LABEL in another class (i:e GameScene.m ), In the game I am using ccLabelBMFont for creating LEVEL label.

Now the Problem is when I am Removing LEVEL label (i:e Level 1) and placing new LEVEL label (i:e Level 2), the code is **not removing "Level 1"** and placing "Level 2" on the previous LEVEL label (i:e Level 1 ).

**Below is my Code for the above same issue, please tell where I am going Wrong :**

```
**Code of HudLayer.h**

#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface HudLayer : CCLayer { 
    CCLabelBMFont * level;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) CCLabelBMFont * level;
@end
```

**Now code for "HudLayer.m" where I am synthethising and using 'level':**

```
#import "HudLayer.h" 
      #import "GameScene.h"

    @implementation HudLayer 

    @synthesize level;
       level = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level 1",level] fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:12];
       [level setAnchorPoint:ccp(1,0.5)];
       [level setPosition:ccp(250,470)]; 
       [level setColor:ccORANGE]; 
       [self addChild:level];
     }
     return self;
     }
     - (void) dealloc {
       [super dealloc];
       [lives release];
     } 

    @end

*HERE IS MY CODE FOR "GameScene.h"*

#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "HudLayer.h"
typedef enum {
    Level1, 
    Level2,
    Level3,
    Level4,
    Level5, 
    Level6,
    Level7, 
    Level8,
    Level9, 
    Level10,
} LevelType;

@interface GameLayer : CCLayer
{
int level;
BOOL ifLevel2Started;
    BOOL ifLevel3Started;
    BOOL ifLevel4Started;
    BOOL ifLevel5Started;
    BOOL ifLevel6Started;
    BOOL ifLevel7Started;
    BOOL ifLevel8Started;
    BOOL ifLevel9Started;
    BOOL ifLevel10Started;
}
@property (assign,readwrite) int level;
@end
```

*AND FINALLY I WANT TO REMOVE THE LEVEL label 1 From HudLayer Class and palce new Label with Name "Level 2" on the basis of Score points:*

```
        #import "GameScene.h"
        #import "HudLayer.h"
        @implementation GameLayer
        @synthesize level;

        @synthesize levelType = _levelType;
        if (self.levelType ==  Level1) {
                [self LevelFeatures];
                ifLevel2Started = FALSE;
            }

            if (self.levelType ==  Level2) {
                [self LevelFeatures1];
                ifLevel3Started = FALSE;
            }

            if (self.levelType ==  Level3) {
                [self LevelFeatures2];
                ifLevel4Started = FALSE;
            }

    -(void)LevelFeatures
    {
        HudLayer * hl = (HudLayer *)[self getChildByTag:KHudLayer]; // * HERE I AM DOING MY MAIN STEP, HERE AM CREATING OBJECT OF **"HudLayer" class** *

        hl.level = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level 2"]  fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:12];
//**HERE AM SETTING NEW Label FOR LEVEL.**
}
```

**I AM FINDING PROBLEM ONLY ON THE ABOVE LINE OF CODE FOR WHICH I WROTE SO BIG QUERY, SO THAT YOU CAN UNDERSTAND MY PROBLEM EXACTLY.**

WHAT I SHOULD WRITE/CODE OVER HERE SO THAT PREVIOUS LABEL COMPLETELY REMOVE AND NEW ONE PLACE OVER IT. (i:e No Overloading of Label happen).

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm , there is a chunk of code missing at the start of your implementation snippet, but I would venture this (with minimal change to your current setup) :

```
 -(void)LevelFeatures {
     HudLayer * hl = (HudLayer *)[self getChildByTag:KHudLayer];
     [hl removeChild:h1.level cleanup:YES];
     hl.level=[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level 2"] 
                                 fontName:@"Marker Felt" 
                                 fontSize:12];
     [hl addChild:hl.level];
}
```

I am not certain why you are retaining level in HudLayer, but just adding as a child to any CCNode descendant will retain it for you. Also, with this kind of code i tend to use tags to regain access to children I add to a CCNode descendant.

Comment: Thankyou for your continued support. I got solution for my query. @YvesLeBorg, The code you provided is absolutely correct but it is not working in my scenario. I written Code "onEnter" Method in my "GameLayer" class and got it working. means I removed the code for Level Label from HudLayer Completely and Declared and defined in the same class(GameLayer) and found it working...Now No need to make Object of HudLayer Class and call by using that class Object  :-)

Answer (score 1):

when you syntesize the label do this:

```
 levelLbl = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:12];
```

and when you set the label in LevelFeatures just use "setString:"  like so:

```
[hl.levelLbl setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level %i",level]];
```